# New line in the text for a CheckBox using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

How di I make a newline in the text for a checkbox? I've tried \n but it didn't work?

EDIT: this is my CheckBox

```xml
<CheckBox xml:space="preserve"  Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,46,0,0" Name="ShowOldRegistrations" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="ShowOldRegistrations_Checked" Unchecked="ShowOldRegistrations_UnChecked">
    <StackPanel  Height="42" Width="108">
        <TextBlock>Line1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Line2</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this in code, or in XAML?

Comment: XAML - sorry for not making that clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF, you can put any control almost anywhere. So you could try this:

```xml
<CheckBox>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>foo</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>bar</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</CheckBox>
```

Also, you need to remove the `Height` property from your checkbox. Of course only one line gets displayed if the height doesn't permit displaying more.

In WPF, in most cases you don't need to (nor should) specify absolute dimensions for your controls. They can adjust automatically quite well.

Comment: Did not work out. It just doesn't show bar, shows foo however :)

Comment: You need to remove the height so that the checkbox can adjust to the added lines. Updated my answer.

Comment: Why do you need the StackPanel ?

Answer (score 13):

```
    <CheckBox Content="Stuff on line1&#x0a;Stuff on line 2" />
```

Answer (score 7):

You should not use a StackPanel for line-breaks, TextBlocks can do that easily:

```xml
<CheckBox>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="Line 1"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="Line 2"/>
    </TextBlock>
</CheckBox>
```